# Problem coming when giving input to return function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class, error-handling

```py
class Library:
    def show(self):
        self.Book_list=["English","Python","Urdu"]
        print(f"\n\nHellow! You can see the available books Below:\n")
        print("\n".join(map(str,self.Book_list)))
    def __init__(self):
        self.BookName=input("\nEnter The Book Name.....").capitalize()
        return self.BookName
     
    def Remove(self):
        if self.BookName in self.Book_list:
            self.Book_list.remove(self.BookName)
            print("You have Got this Book Successfully! Please return the book before 30 Days. ThankYou!")
            return self.Book_list
        else:
            print("Book not Available! Please Request later!")
    def Append(self):
        if self.BookName not in self.Book_list:
            self.Book_list.append(self.BookName)
            print("Hi Thanks for Returning the Book")
            return self.Book_list
        else:
            print("Hi Thanks for Returning the Book")      
class Student:
    def Show_Books(self):return Library.show(self)
    def Borrow(self):return Library.show(self),Library.__init__(self),Library.Remove(self)     
    def Return(self):return Library.__init__(self),Library.Append(self)

while(True):
    stu=Student()
    Msg=("\n\n\n====================== Hi Welcome To The SSUET Library ======================\n\nPlease Select The Option Below:\n\n Press '1' To See The Book's List. \n Press '2' For Borrow.\n Press '3' To Return The Book\n Press '4' for Quit")
    print(Msg)
    slc=int(input("Press the Button..........."))  
    if slc==1:stu.Show_Books()
    elif slc==2:stu.Borrow()
    elif slc==3:stu.Return()
    elif slc==4:
        print("Quit")
        break
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a:\My python course\zproject3\project3.py", line 36, in <module>
    elif slc==3:stu.Return(stu.Return())
  File "a:\My python course\zproject3\project3.py", line 26, in Return
    def Return(self):return Library.__init__(self),Library.Append(self)
  File "a:\My python course\zproject3\project3.py", line 20, in Append
    self.Book_list.append(self.BookName)
AttributeError: 'Student' object has no attribute 'Book_list'
```

Comment: You didn't actually share an error or a specific question. You should read the [tour] and the [ask] page and then add more detail to your post. It's not acceptable to just post code and not even the error. At least paste in the error, please (into your post itself, not into a comment).

Comment: @RandomDavis please check now

Comment: I don't get why you're instantiating a `Library` as a `Student` (by passing the `Student`'s `self` to `Library`'s `__init__`). That's clearly the issue, it's just a matter of whether or not that was your intention, and what your intention actually was.

Comment: I was checking if I could do that but I can't. Acknowledge